# Using Locale as String to display different page

Tags: android, locale, telephonymanager

I have used this line to check the locale.

```
String local = context.getResources().getConfiguration().locale.getDisplayCountry();
Toast.MakeText(this,local,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

It shows Australia (this is where I am).
But I need to display different pages based on locale. so what I have done is

```
if (local=="Australia")
    runpage1();
else
   runpage2();
```

But, it doesn't check the local as "Australia", so straight goes to the else line. I tried like

```
String x;
if (local=="Australia")
     x = "1";
else
   x="2";
 Toast.MakeText(this,x,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

It shows 2. ( I am trying to write to make it as simple as possible, so nobody gets confused with previously asked questions)
Can anybody please suggest me why I am being unable to treat locale as String value ?
I have tried using this too.

```
TelephonyManager teleMgr = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String myCode = teleMgr.getSimCountryIso();
```

But, same thing, myCode is also cannot be checked as String.
Any suggestions will be great.

Comment: use equals method instead of ==

Comment: a string is always compared with equals or equalsIgnoreCase not ==

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: Jeez. This is how the mind farts. Thank you folks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`==` for test only reference.`.equals()` for check `String` values. So you have to compare like this :

```
String x;
if (local.trim().equals("Australia"))
     x = "1";
else
   x="2";
 Toast.MakeText(this,x,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```